# Multiple altair charts generated by the same cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, altair

I have a list of pandas dataframes I named *entries*, which I want to visualize after running code from the same cell. Below is the code I used :

```
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()


for entry in entries :
    entry['ds'] = entry.index
    entry['y'] = entry['count']
    entry['floor'] = 0
    serie = alt.Chart(entry).mark_line(size=2, opacity=0.7, color = 'Black').encode(
        x=alt.X('ds:T',  title ='date'),
        y='y'
    ).interactive().properties(
            title='Evolution of '+entry.event.iloc[0]+' events over time'
        )

    alt.layer(serie)\
                  .properties(width=870, height=450)\
                  .configure_title(fontSize=20)
```

When i run the same code out of the 'for' loop, I get to see the one chart that corresponds to one dataframe, but once I run the code above, I don't get any graphs at all. 

Does anyone know why It's not working or how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: use `chart.display()`

Unless a chart appears at the end of the cell, you must manually display it.

By analogy, if you run

```
x + 1
```

by itself, Python will display the result. However, if you run

```
for x in range(10):
    x + 1
```

Python will not display anything, because the last statement in the cell (in this case the for loop) has no return value to display. Instead you have to write

```
for x in range(10):
    print(x + 1)
```

For altair, the mechanism is similar: if the chart is defined in the last statement in the cell, it will be automatically displayed. Otherwise, you have to manually trigger the display, which you can do using the display method:

```
for i in range(10:
    chart = alt.Chart(...)
    chart.display()
```

For more information on display troubleshooting in Altair, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html